# How to get powerpoint element by id or name with python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Powerpoint has the ability to name or id elements in the presentation. Is there a way to get elements by their name or id using python-pptx? For templates, if there is no data in the element, how can one be sure they are accessing the correct element?